# AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: next.js, prisma, supabase, econnrefused, getserversideprops

First question I'm asking, hoping for a "miracle", safe to say I'm a Jr Developer:

I have a NextJs project and I am using Prisma & Supabase. I made it very simple, I only have one item in the database, one index.js page with a getserversideprops function. When I use axios to get from the API folder, this works locally, but when I deploy it it doesn't work, this is the log on Vercel when I deploy:

[GET] /
22:01:04:79
d: false,
finished: false,
destroyed: false,
decodeStrings: true,
defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
length: 0,
writing: false,
corked: 0,
sync: true,
bufferProcessing: false,
onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
writecb: null,
writelen: 0,
afterWriteTickInfo: null,
buffered: [],
bufferedIndex: 0,
allBuffers: true,
allNoop: true,
pendingcb: 0,
constructed: true,
prefinished: false,
errorEmitted: false,
emitClose: true,
autoDestroy: true,
errored: null,
closed: false,
closeEmitted: false,
[Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
},
_events: [Object: null prototype] {
response: [Function: handleResponse],
error: [Function: handleRequestError],
socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
},
_eventsCount: 3,
_maxListeners: undefined,
_options: {
maxRedirects: 21,
maxBodyLength: Infinity,
protocol: 'http:',
path: '/api/fetches/get-products',
method: 'GET',
headers: [Object: null prototype],
agents: [Object],
auth: undefined,
beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
beforeRedirects: [Object],
hostname: 'localhost',
port: '3000',
agent: undefined,
nativeProtocols: [Object],
pathname: '/api/fetches/get-products'
},
_ended: true,
_ending: true,
_redirectCount: 0,
_redirects: [],
_requestBodyLength: 0,
_requestBodyBuffers: [],
_onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
_currentRequest: ClientRequest {
_events: [Object: null prototype],
_eventsCount: 7,
_maxListeners: undefined,
outputData: [],
outputSize: 0,
writable: true,
destroyed: false,
_last: true,
chunkedEncoding: false,
shouldKeepAlive: false,
maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
_defaultKeepAlive: true,
useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
sendDate: false,
_removedConnection: false,
_removedContLen: false,
_removedTE: false,
strictContentLength: false,
_contentLength: 0,
_hasBody: true,
_trailer: '',
finished: true,
_headerSent: true,
_closed: false,
socket: [Socket],
_header: 'GET /api/fetches/get-products HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
'User-Agent: axios/1.3.0\r\n' +
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
'Connection: close\r\n' +
'\r\n',
_keepAliveTimeout: 0,
_onPendingData: [Function: nop],
agent: [Agent],
socketPath: undefined,
method: 'GET',
maxHeaderSize: undefined,
insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
path: '/api/fetches/get-products',
_ended: false,
res: null,
aborted: false,
timeoutCb: null,
upgradeOrConnect: false,
parser: null,
maxHeadersCount: null,
reusedSocket: false,
host: 'localhost',
protocol: 'http:',
_redirectable: [Circular *1],
[Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
[Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
[Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
[Symbol(corked)]: 0,
[Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
[Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
},
_currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/fetches/get-products',
[Symbol(kCapture)]: false
},
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000
},
page: '/'
}
RequestId: 91b310f3-2890-4aa3-b936-1cea9a199692 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError

this is my index.js

```
export default function Home({products}) {
  return (
    <>
    
   <main>
    {JSON.stringify(products)}
   </main>
    </>
  )
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const port = process.env.API_HOST_PORT || 3000
  const host = `http://localhost:${port}`
  const { data: products } = await axios.get(`${host}/api/fetches/get-products`);

  return { props: { products } };
}
```

the .env files are imported at the top.. You will need to let me know what other information you need from my end so I can inform you.

It's hard for me to debug because it doesn't make sense on my end, I've tried deploying with Vercel and Digital Ocean, but both have a 500 error and when I check the logs it says what I shared. Schema was built correctly, the API Keys are correct. I actually "copied" this from a different project so I could practice more with prisma, but this one doesn't work..

Comment: Your getServerSideProps function is invoking an API on localhost which would not be running when your app is deployed to vercel, hence the error. You can directly connect to your database and fetch the data from getServerSideProps instead of invoking an API

Comment: Amazing! Thank you (my previous comment didn't appear?)